# How to use system string in android

Tags: android, string

I want to use the system string "choose an app",and I find the id is "chooserview_choose_application".

I use it by `getResources().getString(android.R.string.activitychooserview_choose_application`
but show error!
I can only use such as "cancle","copy","no","ok".....!
Is there anyway to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most system resources are private and subject to change without warning. This includes the String resource you referenced.

Other resources (such as `android.R.string.ok`) are public and provided by the SDK for your to use.

All the strings that are available in the SDK [are listed here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.string.html).